# Bash: unparallelize FOR loop execution waiting from grep

Tags: bash, ubuntu, parallel-processing, grep

A grep into a FOR loop to do some stuff with the found lines, inside a FOR loop for looping on values to search, gives parallel execution, with not always predictable results. I would like to force the execution to be not parallel at all.

and example for code:

```
for __loopVar in $(seq 1 32)
do 
    echo "do some stuff no so much time consuming"
    echo "calculate __someTextVar"

    for each_line in  $(grep -HiRF "$__someTextvar" --include \*.log $PATH_logFiles)
    do
        echo "some other stuff, with each line returned by grep"
    done
done
```

The problem, (I assume that) while waiting for grep to return the values, it starts with the following loop ("some stuff") mixing up some global variables.

Note: running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS over multipass.

Comment: That is almost certainly _not_ what's wrong here. For a start, probably fix the errors diagnosed by http://shellcheck.net/; if the problem still persists, show us a [mre] with actual erroneous output.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is nested and I believe it's causing you some confusion as I can't see the purpose of the outer loop.

If you add some basic echos of these values I hope it becomes more clear / obvious:

```
for __loopVar in $(seq 1 3)

do
    echo "__loopVar value is ${__loopVar}"
    for each_line in  $(grep -HiRF "no" --include \sometext.txt $PATH_logFiles)

    do
    echo "__loopVar value2 is ${__loopVar}"
    echo "each_line value2 is ${each_line}"
    done

done
```

Output:

```
__loopVar value is 1
__loopVar value2 is 1
each_line value2 is sometext.txt:another
__loopVar value2 is 1
each_line value2 is b
__loopVar value2 is 1
each_line value2 is sometext.txt:and
__loopVar value2 is 1
each_line value2 is another
__loopVar value2 is 1
each_line value2 is d
__loopVar value is 2
__loopVar value2 is 2
each_line value2 is sometext.txt:another
__loopVar value2 is 2
each_line value2 is b
__loopVar value2 is 2
each_line value2 is sometext.txt:and
__loopVar value2 is 2
each_line value2 is another
__loopVar value2 is 2
each_line value2 is d
__loopVar value is 3
__loopVar value2 is 3
each_line value2 is sometext.txt:another
__loopVar value2 is 3
each_line value2 is b
__loopVar value2 is 3
each_line value2 is sometext.txt:and
__loopVar value2 is 3
each_line value2 is another
__loopVar value2 is 3
each_line value2 is d
```

I think what you want to do is something more like this:

```
IFS=$'\n'
for __loopVar in $(seq 1 3)
do
echo ${__loopVar}
    for each_line in  $(cat sometext.txt)
    do
        echo "some other stuff, with each line returned by grep ${each_line}"
    done
done
```

So escape the spaces (for the cat of the file to get the whole line)
Then loop the lines _loopVar times.

```
$cat sometext.txt
Line a
another b
some other c
and another d
last value is e
$ bash 2.sh
1
some other stuff, with each line returned by grep Line a
some other stuff, with each line returned by grep another b
some other stuff, with each line returned by grep some other c
some other stuff, with each line returned by grep and another d
some other stuff, with each line returned by grep last value is e
2
some other stuff, with each line returned by grep Line a
some other stuff, with each line returned by grep another b
some other stuff, with each line returned by grep some other c
some other stuff, with each line returned by grep and another d
some other stuff, with each line returned by grep last value is e
3
some other stuff, with each line returned by grep Line a
some other stuff, with each line returned by grep another b
some other stuff, with each line returned by grep some other c
some other stuff, with each line returned by grep and another d
some other stuff, with each line returned by grep last value is e
```

This code still needs changing to match your intended behavior since you've provided an incomplete script to begin with. (e.g. change the cat command to your working grep).

Comment: The `cat` in backticks is still not correct; you will actually echo one *word* at a time in the inner loop. See also [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: Yes - I opted for the 'whole line' not one word just because of the variable name. Op doesn't want to iterate over every word - I don't think. I presume he's trying to say 'find me lines which match this and then do some comparison' .... but it's incomplete and not the cause of why they're confused about this 'parallelism' they think is going on which is caused by the nested loops

Comment: Your guess about what's wrong is probably not bad but the proper fix is to use a `while` loop instead. `while IFS= read -r line; do ... done <sometext.txt` and similarly `grep stuff | while IFS= read -r line; do ...`

Comment: Yes I never said the cat was the right solution for them - I even said it needed to be changed to match their output. I think they've tried to do too much or they've done it 'all at once' and haven't broken it down into distinct chunks and tested each aspect individually - and have them come stuck.